# Why does an Object throw an error where Variant does not?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The below code, copied from MSDocs, throws an error after my small modification. Originally, there was early instead of late binding. Nevertheless all of the types (`Namespace`, `SharingItem`) are types of an object. But when the code is modified like in the below sample, it throws an error:

Error Number -> -2147467259

Error Description -> The operation failed

Error Source -> Microsoft Outlook

```vb
Sub MSCodeTest()

 Dim oApp As Object           'Application --> added by me
 Dim oNamespace As Object     'Namespace
 Dim oFolder As Object        'Folder
 Dim oSharingItem As Object   'SharingItem
 On Error GoTo ErrRoutine
 Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")   'added by me
 Set oNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set oFolder = oNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
 Set oSharingItem = oNamespace.CreateSharingItem(oFolder)
 oSharingItem.Display

EndRoutine:

 On Error GoTo 0
 Set oSharingItem = Nothing
 Set oFolder = Nothing
 Set oNamespace = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrRoutine:

 MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly, Err.Number & " - " & Err.source
 GoTo EndRoutine

End Sub
```

On the other hand, if I change Folder from `Object` to `Variant` everything goes smooth. Why does assigning an object type item like `Folder` to an `Object` throw an error, and to a `Variant`, not?

Comment: just wondering, why `Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")` instead of `Set oApp = CreateObject(, "Outlook.Application")`?

Comment: On which line does it fail?

Comment: This is just a sample code. Originally I'm verifying whether it's already open or not. For this sample purposes, we can **assume** it is and if not **open** it.

@TimWilliams It fails on `Set oSharingItem = oNamespace.CreateSharingItem(oFolder)`.

Comment: Using Goto from within an error block is not supported - you should switch that to `Resume EndRoutine`

Comment: Did you remove the outlook object model library reference?  That would cause `olFolderCalendar` to be undefined...

Comment: @TimWilliams I've copied this code from MS Docs, it's a sample (with small modifications), not mine. The `GoTo` is original. I'm trying to highlight something slightly different. And to answer your question, no, I did not remove it.
Original code --> [MS Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.sharingitem)

Comment: @TimWilliams I asked the same question on the CR cross-post, and never got an answer. The failing instruction is `Set oSharingItem = oNamespace.CreateSharingItem(oFolder)`, which indeed only fails if `oNamespace` is declared `As Object`... which is curious indeed (could be a bug in the type library, who knows), but utterly irrelevant if the type library is referenced.

Comment: FWIW I just made a [pull request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/pull/960) to fix this code example.

Comment: Adding `Debug.Print TypeName(oFolder)` immediately after the `Set oFolder` line may help discover this issue - something is being return which does not "fit" into Object but does fit into Variant